# Query Select in SQL postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

We need help to use a command in "SELECT" to return the following information from a bank in PostgreSQL.

"Terminals that had 10 or more occurrences, within 1 hour, with the same user, service, and terminal".

We have the table **TB_TRANSACOES**:

```
Id bigserial NOT NULL,
Dh_transaction timestamp NOT NULL,
Nu_account bigint NOT NULL,
Nu_value bigint NOT NULL,
Co_terminal character varying NOT NULL,
Co_service character varying NOT NULL,
Co_user character varying NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT tb_transacoes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

We have only this part:

```
SELECT * FROM TB_TRANSACOES WHERE CO_TERMINAL >= 10
```

I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

All the records with NumberOfTransactions >  10 should be what you want

```
SELECT 
    Co_terminal 
    , Co_service 
    ,Co_user 
    , COUNT(1) AS NumberOfTransactions
FROM YOUR table
Group by 
    Co_terminal 
    , Co_service 
    ,Co_user 
    ,DATEPART(YEAR, Dh_transaction )
    ,DATEPART(Month, Dh_transaction )
    ,DATEPART(Day, Dh_transaction )
    ,DATEPART(Hour, Dh_transaction )
```

Comment: Does this code pick up the events also in the 1 hour interval?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `lag()`:

```
select distinct co_terminal
from (select t.*,
             lag(dh_transaction, 9) over (partition by co_terminal, co_service, co_user
                                          order by dh_transaction
                                         ) as dh_transaction_9
      from TB_TRANSACOES t
     ) t
where dt_transaction_9 >= dh_transaction - interval '1 hour';
```

This gets the 9th transaction in history.  If it is within an hour, then we have 10 transactions within an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Would the code look like this then?

SELECT 
    Co_terminal 
    , Co_service 
    ,Co_user 
    , COUNT(1) AS NumberOfTransactions
FROM YOUR table
Group by 
    Co_terminal 
    , Co_service 
    ,Co_user 
    ,DATEPART(YEAR, Dh_transaction )
    ,DATEPART(Month, Dh_transaction )
    ,DATEPART(Day, Dh_transaction )
    ,DATEPART(Hour, Dh_transaction )

select distinct co_terminal
from (select t.*,
             lag(dh_transaction, 9) over (partition by co_terminal, co_service, co_user
                                          order by dh_transaction
                                         ) as dh_transaction_9
      from TB_TRANSACOES t
     ) t
where dt_transaction_9 >= dh_transaction - interval '1 hour';